# Comunication between microservices using Openshift and Quarkus

Tags: openshift, microservices, redhat, quarkus

I have some questions related to the communication between microservices inside Openshift. I have the scenario:

- Project

  - Application --> simulate the environment

    - microservice K --> docker image inside a POD K
    - microservice P --> docker image inside a POD P

To implement this approach I am using Quarkus as a framework and as far I know in quarkus we have rest client dependency where we can use to make my request to another microservice.

**How I can know what is the IP and Port to send a request from microservice K to microservice P?**

I know that we can use Consul from Hashicorp but there is other implementation/idea how to implement this approach?

Comment: You should use Kuvernetes services. That lets you use domain names instead of IP addresses, and if a pod restarts (for one reason or another), the service will point to the new one automatically.

Comment: okay, I got the idea but how can we know that exist a new service in runtime?
I agree with that approach but that solution is when you already know that you have two microservices running at the same time, but if you added a new microservices while the other two are running, there is no way (in your solution) to know that a new microservices was added.
That's way a services discovery is a good approach, because in runtime you are able to know that a new microservices is running and you can obtain the DNS or ip:port from that new microservices.
My main question was more about this scenario

Comment: Your microservice has to know upfront what "kind" of other microservices it will call. The style of service discovery you describe then lets you know, at runtime, where are the instances of those "kinds" of microservices. If you use Kubernetes services and domain names, you don't even have to do that. Your service can be backed by an arbitrary number of pods, and load balancing happens automatically. That said, I don't think anything prevents you from using Consul or some other service registry, if that suits you better.

Comment: I try to use your approach from your first comment, but I am getting "host unreached"

http://serviceb.demo.svc.cluster.local

Comment: How did you create the service resource? See also https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ for more info.

Comment: I have created service type ClusterIP for both microservices

Comment: That sounds OK. I can't know what exactly has gone wrong, but I'd suggest to explore the services in the OpenShift web console -- it might be that the service doesn't match any pod, or some of the ports are wrong, or something like that.